# EF throwing "as deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim" UpdateException error

Tags: entity-framework

My code is trying to insert/update data using Entity Framework, but the system is generating the error shown here.

The code is very complex, including different CRUD operations. Code has copyright issues, so I am unable to share actual code.

I am using a console application that runs every 10 minutes and calls the controller method to execute code similar to shown below. It is not actual working code but I have modified it to avoid copyright issues.

```
private void UpdateEconomy(DataEntities context, BudgetVersion project, List<Model.Amount> data)
        {
            var budgetStatus = context.BudgetStatus.First(c => c.Code == "8");

            var subProjectToBeRemoved = context.SubProject.Where(psm => psm.ProjectId == project.ProjectId && psm.BudgetStatusId == budgetStatus.Id).ToList();
            
            foreach (var SubProject in subProjectToBeRemoved)
            {
                context.SubProject.Remove(SubProject);
            }

            // Add the new sub project with budget status 8
            foreach (var sys_SubProject in groupedCost)
            {
                var subProject = new SubProject();

                //Add parent SubProject if not exist
                var parentSubProject = context.SubProject.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SubprojectId == subprojectId && c.ProjectId == project.ProjectId);

                if (parentSubProject == null)
                {
                    context.SubProject.Add(new SubProject
                    {
                        SubprojectId = subprojectId,
                        Created = DateTime.Now,
                        CreatedById = defaultUserId,
                        ProjectId = project.ProjectId
                    });
                }

                subProject.ProjectId = project.ProjectId;
                subProject.Created = DateTime.Now;
                subProject.CreatedById = defaultUserId;
                subProject.PlannedCosts = subProject.PlannedCostAndRevenues ?? new List<PlannedCosts>();

                AddAmountSubProject(sys_SubProject.Children, subProject.PlannedCosts, maxYear, minYear); //It adds costs to current sub project

                subProject.IsOrdered = context.Subproject.Any(c => c.Code == sys_SubProject.Code && c.NotOrderedMapping == null);

                context.SubProject.Add(subProject);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

context.SaveChanges() throws the error.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
 Error when updating record with Id 108219
    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 
An error occurred while updating the entries. 
See the inner exception for details. 
    ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: 
An error occurred while updating the entries. 
    See the inner exception for details. 
---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction 
    (Process ID 195) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: So retry or troubleshoot the deadlock or force the updates to not run concurrently.  With no info, that’s the best we can do.

Comment: You *have* to post a [mre]. It'll take considerable effort, but without it it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Now I have shared the code sample after modifiying the stuff. see the post. Thanks

Comment: @gert-arnold Now you can see the code scenario as well in the main post modified by me

Comment: Unfortunately, that's only one SaveChanges call (assuming that no SaveChanges occurs in hidden code like `AddAmountSubProject`). It doesn't show what else is happening in the database at the same time. I'm afraid only you can tell. Try to find out what causes the deadlock in SQL Server profiler.

Comment: I guess other clients are working with this database at the same time? In order to conflict with them as little as possible, you need to speed up your code as much as possible. For example, removing entities in this way, as shown in your code, is very inefficient. If possible, switch to EF 7 and use the [ExecuteDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.executedelete?view=efcore-7.0) method. Or use some extension for bulk operations from the [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/). I recommend linq2db.

Comment: @GertArnold In AddAmountSubProject() it adds budgets in SubProjectBudget table for SubProject

private ICollection<Budget> AddAmountSubProject(List<Model.Budget> data, Collection<SubProjectBudget> budgets)
{
    foreach (var budget in data.Budgets)
    {
          if (budget  != null)
        {
            budgets.Add(new SubProjectBudget()
            {
                Amount = budget.Amount,
                Year = budget.Year,
                CurrentBudget = budget.CurrentBudget,
            });
        }
    }

    return budgets;
}